# ASA cluster with named interface running PPPoE

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, failover

I am trying to configure an A/S firewall cluster, and I have the interface configured as a PPPoE client. When I try to configure the clustering on ASDM, I get a message saying that high availability is not possible with a named interface configured as a PPPoE or DHCP client.

Why they does it say named? I know naming an interface is not optional in a Cisco ASA. If anyone has advice related to clustering with this way, please share it.

Comment: Apparently, high availability requires the interface IP address be statically configured. Did you ask Cisco TAC?

Comment: No ,my smartnnet is not ready yet

Comment: Is it possible in 9.1 to configure interface without name?